# Paragraph on reportlab's canvas says it doesn't have attribute 'decode'

Tags: canvas, reportlab, paragraph

I'm trying to add a multiline text in reportlab canvas by using `reportlab.platypus.Paragraph` like this:

```
desc = Paragraph("""Hi everyone""")
desc.wrapOn(c, width, height)
desc.drawOn(c, x, y)
```

When I run the script an AttributeError pops up, saying that `Paragraph` has no attribute `decode`.

I'm not sure where's that error coming from (or how to solve it).

**I'm using Python 3.10. Not sure if that's relevant to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, sorry. I forgot I had a regular `drawString` afterwards, pulling from the same "desc" object (which used to be a regular string), and apparently that drawString is the thing that broke (not the code drawing the paragraph itself).

Just... make sure you're not trying to draw a Paragraph with drawString.